# How can I tell if a short (<10s) HTML5 video clip has started properly playing?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, html5-video

Occassionally*   our web app host is slow (not sure why yet) and short video clips in our web app do not play.

Is there some dependable "video started " or "video finished" event that fires in Chrome and Safari (current versions) ?

- We don't know how frequent "occassionally" is (hence this question :) )

Comment: The event you're looking for is "playing". It means video is *actually* playing. Different from "play" which just means the video is "trying" to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp contains all HTML5 audio/video properties, methods, and events.

I have recently implemented an audio recorder and playback using the html5 audio tag and both the **play** & **ended** events always fired (on all ie, safari, firefox, & chrome...we don't support opera so I didn't test it).

In your case, if the play event triggers at least once, and the ended event triggers, I would say this is conclusive that the video played through.

If one or both of those events don't trigger, then I would suggest looking into some of the other properties of the audio/video element (ie. **readyState**, or **canPlayThrough**) to confirm the media source is available.

For more detailed debugging, I suggest the following console.log debugging so you know all events that are occurring.  This example is using jQuery, but can easily be implemented without:

```
var video = $("#player video")[0];
$(video)
.bind('loadstart', function() {
        console.log("Loadstart");
    if(video.networkState === 3){
        console.log("Error loading file");
    }
})  .bind('loadedmetadata', function() {
    console.log('loadedMetaData');
})
.bind('stalled', function (){
    console.log('stalled');
})
.bind('suspend', function(){
    console.log('suspend');
).
.bind('canplaythrough', function() {
    console.log('canplaythrough');
})
.bind('play', function() {
    console.log('play');
})
.bind('pause', function() {
    console.log('pause');
})
.bind('ended', function() {
    console.log('ended');
});
```

While the above code won't solve the problem for you, it may expose events in your video player you weren't aware fired.  I noticed safari will fire stalled, suspend events more than other browsers will.  While it makes sense to include the 'error' event, I never saw it fire myself....YMMV -- Couldn't hurt to include it.

Good luck.